# How to: Load FTP server items into comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, ftp

**How to: Load FTP server items into comboBox**

I do have a FTP server with some elements. Now, I would like to load all html elements of the folder "Texte" into my combo box.

See structure: XYZ.bplaced.net/Test/Texte

- Hello.html
- World.html

This is what I do have so far.

```
string pathTexts = @"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Testumgebung\Texte";
```

Unfortunately, I can just load from a folder on my computer.

```
if (true == CheckPath())
        {
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(pathTexts, "*.html"))
            {
                list.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s));
            }
        }
        comboBox_DataPool.ItemsSource = list;
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting files via FTP, you can't use `Directory.GetFiles()`. You'll have to use an `FtpWebRequest` as shown in this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx).